# Allow multiple remote connection on microsoft remote assistance

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control, remote-connection

We are accessing one XP home pc via microsoft remote assistance. But it allows only single connection at a time. We need 3 more connections at a time **over LAN**. Is there any way to have multiple connections on remote assistance to xp home or xp pro? We were using UltraVNC over lan. But it gives error for excel. So if any option is available, please answer me

Comment: It might help if you indicate the error you recieve.  In the end Windows XP does not official supoprt multiple concurrent remote connections.  If you want that upgrade to Windows Server and purchase the required number of CALs.

Answer (score 6):

The limit is hardcoded in Windows XP, since they aren't selling it as a server OS of any kind.

I can't answer about Remote Assistance, but there are third-party patches that allow multiple connections with plain Remote Desktop: http://www.kood.org/terminal-server-patch/ They need XP Pro, however.

Comment: Yes, I worked with that patches. But any other software available like VNC to allow multiple connection to single pc at a time?. We were using VNC over lan for this purpose. But it gives error for excel while opening themes in excel.

Comment: @grawity - Windows Server 2003 is the Sever version of Windows XP. Of course a new license for Windows Server 2003 is not being sold by Microsoft.

Comment: @ITresearcher Sounds like you need to accept you will need to live without themes or upgrade to a supported version Windows Server.